# How to configure route in Asp.Net WebApi to use action method name as a query parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to invoke diffrent action methods based on the query string parameter, for example, `webapi/mycontroller?action=getuser&id=10` should invoke `mycontroller.getuser(10)` action method and `webapi/mycontroller?action=getallusers` should invoke `mycontroller.getallusers()` action method. I tried to write the routing in the following way:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}?action={action}"
            );
```

But this is not allowed, visual studio gives me the error `The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character`.

Comment: Better to create all your api end points and use route attribute so you get stuff like webapi/getallusers, webapi/getuser/{id} . Read up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: unfortunatelly that is the requirement, the route must be `webapi/mycontroller?action=getallusers` and not `webapi/mycontroller/getallusers`

Comment: Get the requirements changed! It always seems strange that you're having the contract of your service prescribed to you, normally it would be the other way around "here is my API, this is how you use it". I don't see why a client couldn't call the URLs that webapi uses out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

So I've knocked something together that might help you get started

First create a route with custom handler

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: null,
    handler: new CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(config)
);

public class CustomHttpControllerDispatcher : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private IHttpControllerSelector _controllerSelector;
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get { return _configuration; }
    }

    private IHttpControllerSelector ControllerSelector
    {
        get
        {
            if (_controllerSelector == null)
            {
                _controllerSelector = _configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector();
            }
            return _controllerSelector;
        }
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return SendAsyncInternal(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
        Contract.Assert(routeData != null);

        HttpControllerDescriptor httpControllerDescriptor = ControllerSelector.SelectController(request);
        IHttpController httpController = httpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(request);


        foreach (var queryParam in request.GetQueryNameValuePairs())
        {
            routeData.Values.Add(queryParam.Key, queryParam.Value);
        }


        // Create context
        HttpControllerContext controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(_configuration, routeData, request);
        controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
        controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = httpControllerDescriptor;

        return httpController.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then set your methods to get in the controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser([FromUri]int userId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult DoSomething([FromUri]string test)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I've only tried with GET methods, POSTs may just work, but I haven't tested.